# Force longtabu width + skip vertical space between tables

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtabu

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|}
    \hline 
        \multicolumn{4}{|p{60mm}|}{
        \centering \textbf{W2014-000001}

        Heading text for first type: this one has start and end
    } \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{End} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{End} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    Name1 & Start1 & End1 & Val 1 \\ \hline
    Name2 & Start2 & End2 & Val 2 \\ \hline
    Name3 & Start3 & End3 & Val 3 \\ \hline
    Name X & StartX & EndX & ValX \\ \hline
\end{longtabu}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|p{60mm}|}{
        \centering \textbf{W2014-000002}

        Heading text for second type: it has longer names
    } \\  
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{50mm}|}{\textbf{Long name}} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{50mm}|}{\textbf{Long name}} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{50mm}|}{This is a bit longer name 1} & Value1 \\ \hline  
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{50mm}|}{This is a bit longer name 2} & Value2 \\ \hline  
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{50mm}|}{This is a bit longer name 3} & Value3 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{50mm}|}{This is a bit longer name X} & ValueX \\ \hline
      \end{longtabu}                

\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

I want to make them the very same width, and also have zero vertical space between them. In other words, they should look like a single table. Using a single longtabu is not an option, because first heading and other headings are different for the two tables! I wonder why it is not stretching to \textwidth?

Comment: the second table has no `X` column to allow it to stretch. (You have one in the preamble for the first column but that is never used as you replace every entry with `\multicolumn`

Comment: If I use \multicolumn{4}{|X|} instead of \multicolumn{4}{|p{60mm}|} then I get an error "Illegal pream-token (X): `c' used.", so how do I add stretching to a multicolumn?

Comment: why use multicolumn at all the second table could just be `{Xp{10mm}}` no reason to put \multicolumn in every cell

Comment: You are right, although this was just a MWE. In fact I have many columns, some are stretching some are not. Creating expressions manually like the one Harish recommended, and using them in each and every cell is a burden. But since I'm generating the file from a program, I can live with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some dirty method. you have to use proper `width`s

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\tabulinesep = 1mm    %% for better look

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|}
    \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|p{\linewidth}|}{
        \centering \textbf{W2014-000001}

        Heading text for first type: this one has start and end
    } \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{End} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{End} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    Name1 & Start1 & End1 & Val 1 \\ \hline
    Name2 & Start2 & End2 & Val 2 \\ \hline
    Name3 & Start3 & End3 & Val 3 \\ \hline
    Name X & StartX & EndX & ValX \\ \hline
\end{longtabu}
\vskip-2\baselineskip
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|X|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|p{10mm}|}
    %\hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|p{\linewidth}|}{
        \centering \textbf{W2014-000002}

        Heading text for second type: it has longer names
    } \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{0.8\hsize}|}{\textbf{Long name}} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{0.8\hsize}|}{\textbf{Long name}} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{0.8\hsize}|}{This is a bit longer name 1} & Value1 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{0.8\hsize}|}{This is a bit longer name 2} & Value2 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{0.8\hsize}|}{This is a bit longer name 3} & Value3 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|p{0.8\hsize}|}{This is a bit longer name X} & ValueX \\ \hline
      \end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that I had to use \linewidth instead of X within a multicolumn. Sometimes LaTeX is not straightforward to me. Long learning curve. But this is still the best.

Comment: Is there a way to use 10mm column on the right and the remaining space on the left? I understand that 0.8\hsize kinda works. But this was just an MWE. In reality, I have more columns and in some cases, I will have to specify column widths in absolute values.

Comment: @nagylzs: Use `p{\dimexpr\linewidth-10mm-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}` instead of `p{0.8\hsize}` (where `10mm` is the width of right column).

Comment: Okay, so if I have more than one stretching X columns and many more fixed ones, then I have to figure out the right formula and manually enter that into each cell? Is there a better way? :s

Comment: Something like \mymulticolumn{2}{content here} that would calculate the dimension expression for that 2 columns?

Comment: @nagylzs I am afraid not!